# Can we Create a callback between multiple classes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, callback

What I mean is ,

if  `class A` needs data from another `class B`, and that data is supplied to `class B` from `class C` ,

then `class B` gives data to  `class A` (combining of data the data from `class C` and some data of its own).

Now, `class B` can only supply data to `class A` if its receiving from `class C`.

Take a **example**, `class A` launches a popup which is defined in `class B` and  , now `class B`  has `listview` and the data in `listview` is in C. Now if a user click the `listitem` in `listview`, it should close the popup and sends the value on the `listview` to `class A`.

I am new in java, so someone please tell me the main use of interfaces and callbacks here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this you want to use a pattern called Listener or Observer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

General Concept: A Listener (or multiple listeners) gets called by the observed class and supplied with changed data. The Listener can then do something with the data.

In your case: `B` is a Listener of `C` and `A` is a listener of `B`. When `C` has some new data it informs `B`. `B` then combines the data and informs `A`. After `A` is informed the whole chain returns to `C`.

Little caveat you need to know: If you do some blocking operation (Like reading from the filesyste/database/webservice) in one of the Listeners you will block the observed class.

Edit: A good example of the Listener Concept are the ActionListeners (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) in java swing.

Comment: thakyou, for your suggestion but I was asking for javafx ,sorry I forgot to mention my bad!
Can you tell me about javafx

Comment: Never worked with javafx. So sorry can't help you with the specifics in that field.

Comment: ok but, In your experience have you ever came to know about integrating swing on javafx on purpose .

Comment: Can't follow your question there sorry. I have no clue what you want to say :)

Comment: I meant to achieve the functionality.Can we use swing into javafx?

Comment: You don't need swing for this functionality. Swing was just an example how the observer pattern is implemented. The Wikipedia Link I posted should have a decent example for the implementation without swing. You should be able to adapt from there for your usecase